# how do you import oracle table to hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to use sqoop to export oracle table to a hive table:

```
sqoop import --connect  jdbc:oracle:thin:@<server>:1521:<db> --username <user> --password <passwd> --table <table name> --hive-import --hive-table <hive_table_name> -m 1
```

I keep getting this error.

```
2018-09-13 10:55:34,825 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/<table_name> already exists
```

I want to import the oracle table to a hive table. What am I a missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your table already exists on HDFS, you should add target-dir (path on hdfs)

Syntax:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver-name \
      --username <username> \
      --password <password> \
      --driver   <driver-manager-class> \
      --table    <table-name> \
      --target-dir  <target-folder-name>
```

And then create an external Hive table based on your target-dir

Comment: I thought "sqoop import --hive-import" takes the data from oracle table and imports it to hive. Is this not correct? Do I have to add another step to import to hive table?

Comment: I keep getting this error :Could not load org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf. Make sure HIVE_CONF_DIR is set correctly." it is set on basgrc file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hive-import to import from RDBMS to Hive

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/learning \
--username root --password-file "/Learning/sqoop/.password" \
--table employee -m 1 \
--target-dir /Learning/sqoop/import/employee_hive \
--hive-import \
--hive-table employee.employee_hive
```

Change the arguments according to your requirement. Also you can make use of `--create-hive-table` if you want to create a new Hive table.